# When is octal permission 1, 2, or 3 useful?

Tags: permissions

### Alpha notation for permissions:

Three slots: `user, group, other`.

Three letters for each slot and null: `r = read, w = write, x = execute, - = null`.

Ex., `rwxrw-r--` = `user: read-write-execute; group: read-write; other: read`.

### Octal notation for permissions:

A slot for: `user, group, other`;

Three numbers and null for each slot: `read = 4, write = 2, execute = 1; null = 0`;

The sum of the numbers is a unique reference to the permission for the slot.

Ex., `740` = `user: rwx; group: r--; other: ---`.

### My question: when are 1's, 2's, and 3's seen (e.g., `-wx-w---x`):

Commonly seen octal permissions are 777, 755, 700, 740, etc., but I have not seen variants of 1-3 very often (e.g., 333, 311, etc.).  Should octal permissions 1-3 be used frequently?  If so, when?  Can you cite specific examples?

Comment: See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214274/purpose-of-permissions-such-as-0111-or-0333#214276

Comment: I dare to say that write permission without read permission seems to be absurd.

Comment: @Pierre Indeed. But it's fun to see that it really works. :-) One case I can think of is backup files which no one (even yourself) can read, except `root`. I agree, it's a weird setup.

Answer (score 1):

*Useful* and *can be seen* aren't the same thing, and many thinkable combinations aren't seen.

But these permissions are very useful for fast processing in a simple way, because they are algebraic, which means you can add them, subtract, test them. And since they are in groups below 8, the binary operations are nearly as simple in decimal, without thinking in hexadecimal.

```
741=(4+2+1, 4, 1)=111:100:001
```

An owner who wants to write to to the file needs the permission:

```
2-- which is 010:000:000 or
-2- which is 000:010:000 or 
--2 which is 000:000:010
```

it's easy to be seen, that it matches in

```
111:1--:--1 
-1-:---:---
```

- Should octal permissions 1-3 be used frequently?

  No.
- If so, when?

  not applicable
- Can you cite specific examples?

  No.

Comment: I think the question was rather _"When/why would someone do `chmod 200 $file`"_ (giving `--w-------`)?

Comment: Added explicit answers to his 3 last questions.

Comment: M. Becera's link was useful, though: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214274/purpose-of-permissions-such-as-0111-or-0333#214276  .  Even if it's an edge case, it's nice to know when things might appear and why I'm seeing them, despite how unusual they may be.